# How can I listen for clipboard events in node.js?

Tags: windows, linux, node.js, ubuntu, clipboard

I want to be able to listen for clipboard events (the copy event more precisely) in node.js.

I've already used windows keyboard hooks in java... so I'm already a bit familiar with the topic.

And as I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 as my main OS, I'm most interested in a Ubuntu Desktop solution. (but I'd still love to know how to accomplish this for a Windows system too)

Any thoughts?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Jochen

Comment: I'm a little bit confused.  Are you trying to write a web application and listen for clipboard events in the browser, or are you trying to write a command line application and listen for keyboard events on the server?

Comment: I'm trying to listen for clipboard changes on the server. (to post them to a different web app creating a clipboard history)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look at the [node-clipboard module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard) and continually listen for changes to the clipboard using callbacks. Something like:

```
var clipboard = ""
function listenClipboard(){
    var new_clip = getClipboard()
    if (new_clip !== clipboard) {
        clipboard = new_clip
        handleClipboardChange(clipboard)
    }
    setTimeout(listenClipboard, 100)
}
```

Comment: this makes events cry

Comment: I was fifteen when I came up with this. please excuse my horrific coding practices back then

Answer (score 2):

You can try installing my npm package Use [clipboard-event](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard-event)

```
const clipboardListener = require('clipboard-event');

    // To start listening
    clipboardListener.startListening();

    clipboardListener.on('change', () => {
        console.log('Clipboard changed');
    });

    // To stop listening
    clipboardListener.stopListening();
```

Thank you.