# Is there a NodeJS equivalent for detecting clipboard changes?

Tags: node.js, clipboard

In Windows, using C#

```
AddClipboardFormatListener
```

Can be used to detect clipboard changes.

There is a Clipboard manager in Android as well.

I am asking if at all there is one in Nodejs.

Comment: Are you using node.js as a web server?  Or just for a locally run application?  I ask because I'm trying to figure out if you're trying to detect clipboard changes on the computer where node.js is running?  Or on a remote client computer?

Comment: On a locally run computer. Even if it was a webserver, assume I have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through your recent comment on your exact requirement of the possibility of putting a listener to check for clipboard changes, I would advice you to go for the **Clipboard** module and you may further refer **theideasmith** answer in the below thread to put up a listener for the monitoring the clipboard changes.

[How can I listen for clipboard events in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584597/how-can-i-listen-for-clipboard-events-in-node-js)

Hope this helps!

You may want to use one of these packages:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-paste
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard

Comment: I already came across this module. But nowhere did it state it can detect system clipboard changes. I might be wrong, please enlighten me.

Comment: I guess, I didn't read your requirement properly. You can checkout the `copy-paste` module, (checkout my updated answer above) which will meet your requirement.

Comment: This will work but I'll have to use a for loop and continuously check for a change in the clipboard. I am looking for more of an EventListener.

Comment: In that case you will have to go back and consider using the `clipboard` module, checkout `theideasmith` answer in this post => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584597/how-can-i-listen-for-clipboard-events-in-node-js

Comment: Thank you. Please update your answer with the same link and info, so I may accept it.

Comment: @XChikuX Done mate!. Thanks! :-)