# How to detect the changes of system clipboard with nodejs

Tags: node.js, clip

I want to detect the clipboard in my electron app.
Know someone who can answer?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#clipboard-event-definitions ?

Answer (score 0):

It was the issue because Electron doesn't support the change event of the clipboard.
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2280

But thankfully, [sudhakar3697](https://github.com/sudhakar3697) developed a node module [node-clipboard-event](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard-event) which supports clipboard change event for Node.js/Electron.js/NW.js.

Using it, you can listen to the event in this way.

```
const clipboardListener = require('clipboard-event');

// To start listening
clipboardListener.startListening();

clipboardListener.on('change', () => {
    console.log('Clipboard changed');
});

// To stop listening
clipboardListener.stopListening();
```

Comment: node module node-clipboard-event just support win32 & linux, doesn't work on mac

Comment: try to use [node-clipboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard) like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584597/how-can-i-listen-for-clipboard-events-in-node-js?answertab=votes#tab-top)